# Checking neighboring cells in a dynamically allocated 2D array

Tags: c, allocation

I am working on a project in which I need to check neighboring cells of a specific cell in a dynamically allocated 2D `char` array. Basically, If certain neighboring cells are `'X'` for example, then the current cell you are on becomes `'-'`. To allocate the 2D array, I used a single `malloc` call:

```
char *array = (char *)malloc(numRows * numCols * sizeof(char));
```

To access an element while using a double for loop, I use this:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= getNumRows(); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < getNumCols(); j++)
    {
        printf("%c ", **(array + i * getNumCols() + j));
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

How would I access and view the neighboring cells of the current element?

Comment: Your program cannot possibly compile, `+ j*` is invalid syntax. Also, you are allocating a `char *` and dereferencing it two times (`**`): that's wrong, you can only dereference it once.

Comment: probably the condition in the first for loop should be `i < getNumRows()`

Comment: I tried that zois, but then it won't print out the final row of the array.

Comment: _Side note:_ Don't cast the return of `malloc`. And, `sizeof(char)` is _always_ 1 by definition, so using it is extra cruft.

Comment: _Side note:_ Calling `getNumRows` and `getNumCols` in the conditional expression of the `for` loops is probably slow. (e.g.) `getNumRows` probably returns `numRows`, so I'd just do that. Otherwise, consider (e.g.): `int nrow = getNumRows(); for (int i = 0;  i < nrow; ++i)` And, in your inner loop, you're calling `getNumRows` _twice_ on each iteration.

Comment: Your use of `**(array + i*getNumCols() + j)` is incorrect (and gets flagged by the compiler). A single `*` might work. But, the better fix is: `array[i * numCols + j]`

Comment: Define "neighboring" cells. Does this include those cells that are diagonally adjacent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code posted to display the matrix has problems:

- the outer loop should stop when `i == getNumRows()` and
- the `printf` argument should use a single `*` dereferencing operator

Here is a modified version:

```
for (int i = 0; i < getNumRows(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < getNumCols(); j++) {
        printf("%c ", *(array + i * getNumCols() + j));
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Which can also be rewritten to avoid recomputing the matrix sizes repeatedly:

```
for (int i = 0, row = getNumRows(), cols = getNumCols(); i < rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        printf("%c ", array[i * cols + j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Accessing the neighbouring cells of cell `r,c` depends on how you deal with boundaries:

- if boundaries should not be crossed, you must test if `r` and/or `c` are on a boundary to produce between 3 and 8 neighbours.
- if boundaries wrap as a torus, you can just compute `r+/-1 % rows` and `c+/-1 % cols` to always produce 8 neighbours.

To simplify the first case, you can allocate the matrix with 2 extra columns and rows, with `char *array = malloc(sizeof(char) * (numRows + 1) * (numCols + 2));` and use the inner space (active area) this way:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= getNumRows(); i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= getNumCols(); j++) {
        printf("%c ", *(array + i * getNumCols() + j));
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

If you initalize the boundary rows and columns in the matrix as `' '`, you can always access the 8 cells at `r+/-1, c+/-1` and check for `'X'` without special casing the boundary rows of the active part.

Accessing these neighbouring cells can be done according to the implementation choices:

```
 int rows = getNumRows(), cols = getNumCols();
 char *cellp = array + r * cols + c;

 // using extra rows and columns
 char top_1 = cellp[-cols - 1];
 char top_2 = cellp[-cols];
 char top_3 = cellp[-cols + 1];
 char mid_1 = cellp[-1];
 char mid_2 = cellp[+1];
 char bot_1 = cellp[+cols - 1];
 char bot_2 = cellp[+cols];
 char bot_3 = cellp[+cols + 1];

 // using torus-like wrapping
 char top_1 = array[(r + rows - 1) % rows * cols + (c + cols - 1) % cols];
 char top_2 = array[(r + rows - 1) % rows * cols + c];
 char top_3 = array[(r + rows - 1) % rows * cols + (c + 1) % cols];
 char mid_1 = array[r * cols + (c + cols - 1) % cols];
 char mid_2 = array[r * cols + (c + 1)];
 char bot_1 = array[(r + 1) % rows * cols + (c + cols - 1) % cols];
 char bot_2 = array[(r + 1) % rows * cols + c];
 char bot_3 = array[(r + 1) % rows * cols + (c + 1) % cols];

 // using tests
 char top_1 = (r == 0        || c == 0       ) ? 0 : cellp[-cols - 1];
 char top_2 = (r == 0                        ) ? 0 : cellp[-cols];
 char top_3 = (r == 0        || c == cols - 1) ? 0 : cellp[-cols + 1];
 char mid_1 = (                 c == 0       ) ? 0 : cellp[-1];
 char mid_2 = (                 c == cols - 1) ? 0 : cellp[+1];
 char bot_1 = (r == rows - 1 || c == 0       ) ? 0 : cellp[+cols - 1];
 char bot_2 = (r == rows - 1                 ) ? 0 : cellp[+cols];
 char bot_3 = (r == rows - 1 || c == cols - 1) ? 0 : cellp[+cols + 1];
```

Comment: Just thinking why simply do not use a pointer to an array and do not have all those arithmetic problems. (BTW It is not my DV. Interesting why your answer was DVted)

Comment: @0___________: my initial answer did not address the OP's question: how to access neighboring cells, it merely pointed some problems in the posted code.

Comment: Down vote was because the original answer did not answer the question which is about accessing the neighbouring cells. That's been fixed so the down vote has been reversed to an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a pointer to the array. It makes array indexing much easier. Example prints neighbouring cells.

```
void print_n(void *arr, size_t nrows, size_t ncols, size_t col, size_t row)
{
    int (*array)[nrows][ncols] = arr;

    if(col) printf("Left: %d\n", (*array)[row][col - 1]);
    if(col < ncols - 1) printf("Right: %d\n", (*array)[row][col + 1]);
    if(row) printf("Top: %d\n", (*array)[row - 1][col]);
    if(row < nrows - 1) printf("Right: %d\n", (*array)[row + 1][col]);
}

int main(void)
{
    size_t ncols = 10, nrows = 20;
    int (*array)[nrows][ncols] = malloc(sizeof(*array));

    for(size_t row = 0; row < nrows; row++)
        for(size_t col = 0; col < ncols; col++)
            (*array)[row][col] = row * 100 + col;
    print_n(array, nrows, ncols, 6, 7);
    free(array);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/7Yoff5

Comment: If you're going to use a VLA, why bother with a `void *` pointer in the first place?  You can use VLAs all around: `void print_n( size_t nrows, size_t ncols, int array[nrows][ncols], ...)`